# Paypal payment made but IPN not triggered due to down server on merchant website

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Could anybody please tell me what happen if payment is made on PayPal but IPN is not triggered because server is down on merchant website.

How paypal will check and authorize the payment on merchant server?

Comment: If your server is down when an IPN is triggered, PayPal will see the failure response back to their server, and the IPN system will re-send the IPN again later.  It will keep doing this until it gets a successful result back from your IPN script.  I'm pretty sure it will try again in 30 seconds, then 1 min, then 2 min, then 4 min, etc. until it works.  If you have this happening too much your IPNs will get placed in a delayed queue, so you definitely want to get it resolved ASAP.

Answer (score 4):

IPN is an (optional) notification service, it isn't related to the transaction (aka "checkout flow", "payment flow") per se. It notifies the receiver (of the IPN message) of event(s) in transactions that occur **at Paypal**.

> [**Instant Payment Notification**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)
>
> Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that automatically notifies merchants of events related to PayPal transactions. Merchants can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, like automatically fulfilling orders and providing customers with order status.
>   ...
>
> **Using IPN in your checkout flow**
>
> Although PayPal usually processes IPN messages immediately, IPN is not synchronized with actions on your website. Internet connectivity
>   is not always 100% reliable and IPN messages can be lost or delayed.
>   The IPN service automatically resends messages until the listener
>   acknowledges them. The service resends messages for up to 4 days.
>
> *Because IPN is not a real-time service, your checkout flow should not
>   wait for the IPN message before it is allowed to complete. If the
>   checkout flow is dependent on receiving an IPN message, processing can
>   be delayed by system load or other reasons. You should configure your
>   checkout flow to handle a possible delay.*

Hth..